# Get variable list of a class

Tags: c#

```
Class foo
{
   public string name;
   public int age;
   public datetime BirthDate;
}
```

I have the above class.

I want the list of variables of the foo class.

I tried

```
foo fooObj= new foo();
fooObj.GetType().GetProperties()
```

This returned me 0 properties.

Obviously this wont work as there are no properties in class foo.

Comment: These are fields, not properties

Comment: In most cases reflection is the wrong tool, why do you need to get the proeprties/fields in this way at all?

Comment: You got `Fields` there not `Properties`.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter. if reflection is the wrong tool then whats the best way to access properties/fields?

Comment: As a random aside: why aren't those properties? `public string Name {get;set;}` would be preferable in **every**. **single**. **way**. And actually, `age` and `BirthDate` are redundant anyway... (one implies the other)

Comment: @MARKANDBhatt: `string fooName = foo.Name;` (you should also follow .NET [naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043(v=vs.110).aspx))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
new foo().GetType().GetFields()
```

Those are `fields` and not `properties` and `GetType` is a method of `object`.

Just doing `foo.GetType()` will throw an error.

Comment: Why a `new` as the first word in the code?

Comment: @gunr2171, sorry missed a `()` I'm creating a object of `foo` with `new` operator

Answer (score 10):

Your class has *fields*, not *properties*.  A property has getter and setter methods, while a field just stores data.

Try

```
typeof(foo).GetFields()
```

or change your fields to properties:

```
Class foo
{
   public string name {get; set;}
   public int age {get; set;}
   public datetime BirthDate {get; set;}
}
```

Or, to get fields *and* properties, use:

```
typeof(foo).GetMembers()
           .Where(mi => mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field || 
                        mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property);
```